# SQLite Database Returning 1970-01-01

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am working on a shopping application, and I am trying to set up the user profile function. Users can register an account, with a date stored in the account. I used SQLite Database to store and it successfully stored the correct date, but when I retrieve, it always return me 1970-01-01 regardless of what I stored.

I'm using java.utils.Date

This is the database:

---

```
private String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "("
        + COLUMN_USER_NO + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
        + COLUMN_USERNAME + " TEXT," + COLUMN_PASSWORD + " TEXT,"
        + COLUMN_TELEPHONE + " TEXT," + COLUMN_ADDRESS + " TEXT,"
        + COLUMN_CREDITCARD_NO + " INTEGER," + COLUMN_SECURITY_NO + " INTEGER,"
        + COLUMN_EXPIRY_DATE + " LONG," + COLUMN_RATING + " INTEGER, "
        + COLUMN_TOTAL_RATED_BY + " INTEGER" + ")";
```

---

This is how I retrieve the user's data:

---

```
public User getUser(String username) {

    // array of columns to fetch
    String[] columns = {
            COLUMN_USER_NO,
            COLUMN_USERNAME,
            COLUMN_PASSWORD,
            COLUMN_TELEPHONE,
            COLUMN_ADDRESS,
            COLUMN_CREDITCARD_NO,
            COLUMN_SECURITY_NO,
            COLUMN_EXPIRY_DATE,
            COLUMN_RATING,
            COLUMN_TOTAL_RATED_BY
    };

    String sortOrder = COLUMN_USER_NO + " ASC";

    String selection = COLUMN_USERNAME + " =?";

    String[] selectionArgs = {username};

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    // query the user table
    /**
     * Here query function is used to fetch records from user table this function works like we use sql query.
     * SQL query equivalent to this query function is
     * SELECT user_no,user_name,user_email,password FROM user ORDER BY user_name;
     */
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER,
            columns,    //columns to return
            selection,        //columns for the WHERE clause
            selectionArgs,        //The values for the WHERE clause
            null,       //group the rows
            null,
            sortOrder);       //filter by row groups

        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        User u1 = new User();
        u1.setUserNo(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USER_NO))));
        u1.setUsername(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USERNAME)));
        u1.setPassword(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PASSWORD)));
        u1.setTelephone(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_TELEPHONE)));
        u1.setAddress(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ADDRESS)));
        u1.setCreditCardNo(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_CREDITCARD_NO))));
        u1.setSecurityNo(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_SECURITY_NO))));
        u1.setExpiryDate(new Date(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_EXPIRY_DATE))));
        u1.setRating(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_RATING))));
        u1.setTotalRatedBy(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_TOTAL_RATED_BY))));

     return u1;
```

}

---

And this is the line I used to retrieve my date from a specific user:

---

`mTextViewProfileCreditCardExpiryDate.setText(user.getExpiryDate());`

---

How can I retrieve the correct stored date?

Comment: maybe your insert / update is not working correct?  How do you confirm that there is value in this columns?

Comment: A zero in a variable that represents 'millis-since-epoch' would appear as Jan 1, 1970.

Comment: Have you tried debugging and looking at the variables and database records at each step?

Comment: Can you log the `user.getExpiryDate()`

Comment: Also, What do you mean "specific user"?. What do you use for getting it

Comment: After registering a user, I had downloaded the database file from the device file explorer and looked into it using SQLite DB Browser and confirmed that the date I entered is stored correctly.

Comment: Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT+00:00 1970

This is what I get when I log user.getExpiryDate()

To get a specific user, I will use the getUser() function to retrieve the user object and then get the date from it.